# Load part of page separately after page load in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I want to create complex blog page with meteor. I have a template with two sub template as below:

```
<template name="singlePostPage">
    {{> post }}
    {{#each comments}}
        {{> comment}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

I want to load **post** when page is loading and after post load completely then load **comments**. (like [disqus](https://disqus.com/) comment system that load after entire page load)

Please guide me how to do this and what packages may useful for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a session variable or reactive variable when the post template has been rendered, and then have a handlebars `{{#if}}` to show the comments based on the value of that variable. Something like below should work.

.js file (Sessions)

```
Template.post.onRendered(function() {
    Session.set("postRendered", true);
});

Template.singlePostPage.helpers({
    postRendered: function() {
        return Session.get("postRendered");
    }
});
```

Just make sure that the `postRendered` Session variable is set to false or null when you first load the `singlePostPage` template. If you want to use a reactive variable:

Add this package:

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

And use this .js code:

```
var postRendered = new ReactiveVar(false);
Template.post.onRendered(function() {
    postRendered.set(true);
});

Template.singlePostPage.helpers({
    postRendered: function() {
        return postRendered.get();
    }
});
```

For both examples you can use this .html file

```
<template name="singlePostPage">
    {{> post }}
    {{#if postRendered}}
        {{#each comments}}
            {{> comment}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: I think it is better to use reactiveVar here

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I want to fetch comments data after singlePostPage load. Where is the best place for add subscribe and query comments?